# Why don't the absolute value functions in C accept const inputs?

Tags: c, function, constants, pass-by-value

In C, the prototype for the absolute value function (that accepts a float) is

```
 float fabsf( float );
```

Why doesn't this prototype accept a constant value, like this:

```
 float fabsf( float const );
```

fabsf won't change the value of the input, will it?

If I have a function that accepts an input and calls fabsf, am I forced to avoid specifying the input as const?

What is the appropriate way to handle const correctness in this situation?

Comment: `const` is redundant here, what do you imagne is happening?

Comment: @M.M I expect it would create a compile time error if I tried to change the value of the input inside the function.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: Since the parameter inside the function is a local copy, adding `const` is completely meaningless.

Comment: "*fabsf won't change the value of the input, will it?*" How could you tell? The parameter is passed by value.

Comment: The following code is legal C: `float const x = -1.0; float y = fabsf(x);` so it seems to me that `fabsf` **does** accept const inputs. There's no way to say "you can pass me a `float` by value but you can't pass a `const float`." (And as we see in the answers, C does not provide a way to **require** that the input to a function be a `float const`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit**

As M.M commented, on parameters in *prototypes* the `const` is ignored. The edited source of the original answer (see below) shows this:

```
float correct(float const value);

float erroneous(float const value);

float changer(float value);

float correct(float value) {
  return -value;
}

float erroneous(float value) {
  value = -value;
  return value;
}

float changer(float value) {
    value = -value;
    return value;
}
```

There is no error message.

Anyway, I'll leave the original in place in the hope it might help.

---

**Original**

The `const` at a parameter makes this *parameter* read-only inside the function.

For example:

```
float correct(float const value) {
  return -value;
}

float erroneous(float const value) {
  value = -value;
  return value;
}

float changer(float value) {
  value = -value;
  return value;
}
```

This source will not compile without error message.

The function `correct()` will read the given value, change its sign, and return the negated value.

The function `erroneous()` seems to do effectively the same, except that there is an assignment to the parameter. But as the parameter is `const` this is not allowed.

Next, the function `changer()` will work as the both before, but it gives no errors.

Let's look at the call site:

```
float f = 3.14159;
float g = correct(f); // or erroneous(f) or changer(f)
```

The variable `f` given as an argument will be *copied* into the parameter `value`. It will never change even if `changer()` will be called.

You might like to look at parameters as some kind of local variables. Actually they are mostly handled like this in the generated machine code.

---

So, why do you see `const` sometimes? You see it if a *pointer* is defined as parameter.

When you don't want the value *pointed to* to be changed, you need to add `const`; but do it at the correct position!

```
void effective(int const * pointer);

void futile(int * const pointer);

void possible_but_overly_restricted(int const * const pointer);
```

Comment: The question is about prototypes though,  the prototype `float fabsf( float const );` has nothing to do with the function implementation (which does not have to repeat the `const`), in fact the `const` is ignored entirely in the prototype

Comment: Can const go in function definitions without going in the prototype?

Comment: @user24205 yes it can

Answer (score 34):

C uses pass by value. The value for the parameter of a function is a copy of the argument you give.

It is OK to copy both const and non-const floats, and the result is a non-const float.

It is similar to assignment:

```
const float f = 5.5f;
float g = f;   // OK
```

In fact, the language specifies that the value of an expression can never be `const`, i.e. when a value is read from a variable, that value is not `const` even if the variable was.

Answer (score 8):

Because the C language uses pass by value semantics, *any* argument that you pass to it, while it could be modified internally, doesn't directly affect the value you pass in.

This means that from the caller's perspective, `float fabsf( float );` and `float fabsf( const float );` are the same.  So there's no point in making the parameter `const`.

Where it *does* make sense to use `const` is if the parameter you pass in is a pointer, for example:

```
void print_string(char *str)
```

This function, despite what the name suggests, can dereference the given pointer and modify what it points, i.e. `str[0] = 'x'`, to result in a change viewable by the calling function.  If this function were defined like this:

```
void print_string(const char *str)
```

The caller is ensured that function can't perform any modifications to what `str` points to.

Comment: "The caller is ensured that function can't perform any modifications ..." is not true. The function knows the address of the data and can therefore modify it, with, e.g.: `((char*)str)[0] = 'f'`. The `const ... *` in the arguments list is therefore only a "declaration of intent".

Answer (score 5):

To add a language lawyer perspective:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types.
>   Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of
>   parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types**. 
>   [..]
>   In the determination of type
>   compatibility and of a composite type, [..] each **parameter declared with qualified type
>   is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type**.
>
> N1570 6.7.6.3/15

That means these two are compatible:

```c
void foo(int const);
void foo(int);
```

Therefore you can write the prototype with or without `const` (which means without makes more sense; less to type / read) and can add `const` in the function definition if you want to avoid accidentally modifying the (copied - call by value!) parameter inside the functions body.